# All of my websites are using dark mode in Google Chrome but unclear why?

Tags: google-chrome

I have Google Chrome installed with google-chrome-stable from apt on ubuntu 21.04

It says the version is Version 92.0.4515.107 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Currently all websites have a dark mode which I don't necessarily want.

Chromium and Firefox on the same computer do not have the same issue

For example this website (unix.stackexchange.com) looks like this

Note that interestingly, in devtools, running `window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;` is false so it might not be related to a website dark mode preference automatically getting turned on(?)

Happens in private browsing and normal also, so shouldnt be extension related

[image: screenshot of stackexchange with page half in dark mode]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had in the chrome experiments in chrome://flags

"Force Dark Mode for Web Contents" enabled

Disabling it fixed it